# sudo service command not found when installing mongodb

Tags: osx, services

I am currently on OS/X using macbook. I want to stop the instance of mongodb service running. Hence I tried:

```
> sudo service mongodb stop
sudo: service: command not found
```

After looking up on Google, they asked me to add PATH hence I did the following:

```
> `vim ~/.bash_profile` (created a new bash_profile) and added the following there:

   export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

It does not seem to work and I still get the same error:

Answer (score 9):

There is no service command on OS X.   It's probably being managed by launchd which means you'll need to do the following ([found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495293/whats-a-clean-way-to-stop-mongod-on-mac-os-x)).  Note that there are 2 answers below, one if you installed using home-brew the other not.

> It's probably because launchctl is managing your mongod instance. If
>   you want to start and shutdown mongod instance, unload that first:
>
> ```
> launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
> ```
>
> Then start mongod manually:
>
> ```
> mongod -f path/to/mongod.conf --fork
> ```
>
> You can find your mongod.conf location from
>   `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist`.
>
> After that, `db.shutdownServer()` would work just fine.
>
> Added Feb 22 2014:
>
> If you have mongodb installed via homebrew, homebrew actually has a
>   handy `brew services` command. To show current running services:
>
> `brew services list`
>
> To start mongodb:
>
> `brew services start mongodb`
>
> To stop mongodb if it's already running:
>
> `brew services stop mongodb`

Comment: "brew services" command does not exist for me:

$ brew services
Error: Unknown command: services

Comment: To install brew services:
`$ brew tap homebrew/services`

Then, install a formula as usual:
`$ brew install mongo`

You may now start/stop formula a service:
`$ brew services start mongo`
`$ brew services stop mongo`

More info at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Answer (score 0):

These commands save my day thanks in advance.

To start mongodb:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

To stop mongodb if it's already running:

```
brew services stop mongodb
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on the Unix SE! These are two different commands. The OP wants to start/stop mongodb, but also he wants to know, why the "service" commands don't work for him. Its probably reason, that he read these on some Unix/Linux docs, and macosx is a little bit different. Give more explanation in your answers, so you will get more upvotes.

Comment: if brew services start mongodb not work please try this command:      sudo services start mongodb       To stop mongodb if it's already running:    brew services stop mongodb  if this command not work please try this one :      sudo services stop mongodb